# Почему не срабатывает условие modx?

Tags: modx

```
[[+idx:mod=`2`:is=`0`:and:neq=`[[+total]]`:then=`111111">`]]
```

Нужно вывести текст после каждой второй записи, кроме последней. Вот эта часть не работает :and:neq=`[[+total]]` вроде в инете всё изучил и правильно составил. Есть тут сенсеи modx?

Comment: А если оставить только [[+total]], на последней записи выводит текст? у вас этот плейсхолдер установлен?

Answer (score 0):

```
[[+idx:neq=`[[+total]]`:and:mod=`2`:is=`0`:then=`111111111`]]
```

Comment: Или так, в моем случае это более универсально, если необходимо использовать в обеих частях до и после and несколько модификаторов, к примеру выводить текст у каждой четной и каждой 5 записи. P.S, исправьте свой ответ, добавьте 4 пробела перед строкой, он сделает вашу строку кодом, а так апострофы съедаются

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

У вас получается, что выводить текст если остаток от деления на 2 равен (0 и меньше кол-ва записей). Чтобы не выводил у последней записи, надо использовать and совместно с оператором if

```
[[+idx:mod=`2`:is=`0`:and:if=`[[+idx]]`:neq=`[[+total]]`:then=`111111">`]]
```

Т.е. выводить текст (если остаток от деления равен 0) И (если не последняя запись)